# First Cell Became Empty and after scrolling all cell text became disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using UITableView and using Custom cell.I am seting a UILabel . My first row of UITableView is empty.UILabel are on starting with second row. And after scrolling upward UILabel became disappear.And scrolling downward UILabel appear.How we resolve this problem.
on view did Load

```
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustumCell";

    CustumCell *cell = (CustumCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 200 ,200 )];
    label.text=@"hello";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40;
}
```

Comment: NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d CustumCell",indexPath.row]; add this line in your cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: Do you understand the principle of reusable cells and cell identifiers?

Comment: not affected label diappear and first row still empty

Comment: create a custom cell in storyboard, give it an identifier, use that identifier in the code, subclass the cell, add a uilabel, store it as an IBOutlet, access it from the code. -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: You are re-adding the text field each time you re-use the cell and you don't keep a reference to the text field so you can't reuse it. You should only add the text field inside the `if (cell==nil)`  and you should store the reference in a property of your cell class rather than a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below code

```
CustumCell *cell = (CustumCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
{
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 200 ,200 )];
label.tag=1;
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    }

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];    
    label.text=@"hello";
```

No need to allocate the label each time. You shoild allocate it only when cell is nil.
For others try to fetch the label using tag

Comment: Do one thing. Cell height is 40 and label height is 200. so set it to 40.